# How to remove the key control so users won't be able to use - and + to zoom?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using Openlayers on Drupal 7 and I'm trying to remove the key control so the person won't be able to use the key - and + to zoom.

```
for (map in Drupal.settings.openlayers.maps) {
    data = jQuery('#' + map).data('openlayers').openlayers;
    jQuery(data.controls).each(function(){
        data.removeControl((this));
    });
}
```

So with this code I delete all the controls, but in the end it's still working !

On the file openlayers_behavior_keyboarddefaults.js if I comment the line `Drupal.openlayers.addControl(data.openlayers, 'KeyboardDefaults');`

The keyboard zoom is not working !

In drupal there is an option witch can do that, but that not what I'm looking for.

If I don't find any solution I still can change the value in the DataBase but I would like not using this method, (I'd prefere to learn OL instead :))

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution after spending a lot of time in OpenLayers library.
Basically the solution is to create a new behavior which will override the function OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults, after that you will have to comment the lines which use the - and + code keys, and in the end force to render the behavior.

This Solution works for Drupal 7

Create a new module and don't forget to add these 2 lines in the info file:

```
dependencies[] = openlayers
dependencies[] = geofield
```

The new behavior

```
function mymodule_openlayers_behaviors(){
  return array(
    'openlayers_behavior_OKC' => array(
      'title' => t('Override key control'),
      'description' => t('Remove the - and + zoom key'),
      'type' => 'behaviors',
      // 'file' => 'includes/openlayers_behavior_yop.inc',
      'behavior' => array(
        'class' => 'openlayers_behavior_OKC',
        'parent' => 'openlayers_behavior',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/includes',
        'file' => 'openlayers_behavior_OKC.inc',

      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

the file includes/openlayers_behavior_OKC.inc will call the js to override the function.

```
class openlayers_behavior_OKC extends openlayers_behavior {
  /**
   * Provide initial values for options.
   */
  function options_init() {
    return array(
      'keyboarddefaults' => '',
    );
  }

  // /**
  //  * Render.
  //  */

  function render(&$map) {
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/js/openlayers_behavior_OKC.js');
      return $this->options;
    }

}
```

after that you just need to rewrite the function OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults (I've comment the lines related to the + and - but you can choose or add new keys if you want to)
Here is the file js/openlayers_behavior_OKC.js

```
/**
 * @file
 * JS Implementation of OpenLayers behavior.
 */

/**
 * Keyboard Defaults Behavior.  Implements the KeyboardDefaults OpenLayers
 * Control.
 */
OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {

    /**
     * APIProperty: autoActivate
     * {Boolean} Activate the control when it is added to a map.  Default is
     *     true.
     */
    autoActivate: true,

    /**
     * APIProperty: slideFactor
     * Pixels to slide by.
     */
    slideFactor: 75,

    /**
     * APIProperty: observeElement
     * {DOMelement|String} The DOM element to handle keys for. You
     *     can use the map div here, to have the navigation keys
     *     work when the map div has the focus. If undefined the
     *     document is used.
     */
    observeElement: null,

    /**
     * Constructor: OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults
     */

    /**
     * Method: draw
     * Create handler.
     */
    draw: function() {
        var observeElement = this.observeElement || document;
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Keyboard( this,
                {"keydown": this.defaultKeyPress},
                {observeElement: observeElement}
        );
    },

    /**
     * Method: defaultKeyPress
     * When handling the key event, we only use evt.keyCode. This holds 
     * some drawbacks, though we get around them below. When interpretting
     * the keycodes below (including the comments associated with them),
     * consult the URL below. For instance, the Safari browser returns
     * "IE keycodes", and so is supported by any keycode labeled "IE".
     * 
     * Very informative URL:
     *    http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html
     *
     * Parameters:
     * evt - {Event} 
     */
    defaultKeyPress: function (evt) {
        var size, handled = true;
        switch(evt.keyCode) {
            case OpenLayers.Event.KEY_LEFT:
                this.map.pan(-this.slideFactor, 0);
                break;
            case OpenLayers.Event.KEY_RIGHT: 
                this.map.pan(this.slideFactor, 0);
                break;
            case OpenLayers.Event.KEY_UP:
                this.map.pan(0, -this.slideFactor);
                break;
            case OpenLayers.Event.KEY_DOWN:
                this.map.pan(0, this.slideFactor);
                break;

            case 33: // Page Up. Same in all browsers.
                size = this.map.getSize();
                this.map.pan(0, -0.75*size.h);
                break;
            case 34: // Page Down. Same in all browsers.
                size = this.map.getSize();
                this.map.pan(0, 0.75*size.h);
                break; 
            case 35: // End. Same in all browsers.
                size = this.map.getSize();
                this.map.pan(0.75*size.w, 0);
                break; 
            case 36: // Home. Same in all browsers.
                size = this.map.getSize();
                this.map.pan(-0.75*size.w, 0);
                break; 

/*            case 43:  // +/= (ASCII), keypad + (ASCII, Opera)
            case 61:  // +/= (Mozilla, Opera, some ASCII)
            case 187: // +/= (IE)
            case 107: // keypad + (IE, Mozilla)
                this.map.zoomIn();
                break; 
            case 45:  // -/_ (ASCII, Opera), keypad - (ASCII, Opera)
            case 109: // -/_ (Mozilla), keypad - (Mozilla, IE)
            case 189: // -/_ (IE)
            case 95:  // -/_ (some ASCII)
                this.map.zoomOut();
                break; */
            default:
                handled = false;
        }
        if (handled) {
            // prevent browser default not to move the page
            // when moving the page with the keyboard
            OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
        }
    },

    CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults"
});
```